# Apple Watch - Another launch session is already waiting to debug the app extension with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode7, apple-watch

I was debugging my Apple Watch extension with my app, and I've suddenly started to get Another launch session is already waiting to debug the app extension with identifier : *my watch extension id* error. I've restarted Xcode, my phone, and my watch, then tried again, but I'm still getting the same error. After restarting all, I've selected my Watch target to run on my phone + watch, hit Run once, and waited. I'm on iOS 9.2 and watchOS 2.1.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I see you didn't try restarting the computer, worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my Mac fixed the issue.

Comment: I hate when i have to do this, but it's the solution for this issue

Comment: no this is not the fix ALamp answer is more accurate --- this is like giving up!

Comment: @CaffeineShots well, in all of my cases, ALamp's answer never solved my issue while restarting my Mac did. so, for my case, *this* is the fix, not the other one.

Answer (score 11):

Try going to the stop button (top-left of Xcode) and make sure there isn't a dropdown icon at the bottom-right of the stop button. If there is, click it, and then click each application listed to stop all applications. Then, rebuild your application.